# Read currently set spindown timeout of disk

Tags: disk, hdparm

I can set the spindown timeout of a disk via `hdparm -S <timeout> /dev/sda`.
How can I verify, i.e. read out, what timeout `/dev/sda` has set at any given moment?
(I read `man hdparm` to no avail.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`hdparm` is a thin wrapper around various drive command sets, in particular ATA/ATAPI. These command sets don’t provide a way to retrieve timeouts; see for example [the draft ATA8-ACS](https://web.archive.org/web/20141010045105if_/http://www.t13.org/documents/UploadedDocuments/docs2008/D1699r6a-ATA8-ACS.pdf) — the only “idle” or “standby”-related commands are commands to immediately place the drive in a given power mode or to *set* the corresponding timeout. Even the “check power mode” (E5h) command only returns the current power mode, it doesn’t provide any information on timeouts (either their current threshold, or their current value).

Comment: That's a bummer. But thanks for the clarification.